# Assigning object properties (in a loop) and including a setter results in undefined values

Tags: javascript, object, defineproperty

This is my first attempt at using Javascript's `Object.defineProperty` and/or `defineProperties` and apparently I'm doing it completely incorrectly.  I am passing a cfg object into a Javascript function constructor, then inside that constructor am looping over the config and

1. Calling Object.defineProperty on each cfg key
2. Assigning `this[key] = cfg[key]`

However every `this[key]` emerges with `undefined` as it's value.  I've tried a few different things, such as setting the `writable` attribute to true, but got an error that this conflicts with the `set/function`.  I've also tried using `Object.defineProperties` with the same result.  I don't think it's a scoping issue with `this` and have even used `.bind(this)` on the setters to be sure, but to no avail.  The code is can be run at https://repl.it/@dexygen/js-define-properties and I am including it below inline.  Expected result of course rather than `undefined` is that `this.foo` e.g. will contain the string 'foo' from `cfg.foo` passed into the object constructor function

```
let myObj = new ObjInstance({
    foo: 'foo',
    bar: 'bar',
    baz: 'baz'
});

function ObjInstance(cfg) {
    for (let key in cfg) {
      Object.defineProperty(this, key, {
          configurable: true,
          enumerable: true,
          // writable: true, // throws error in conjunction with set function
          set: (function(val) {
              console.log('this[' + key + ']: ' + this[key]); //undefined :(
          }).bind(this)
      });
      console.log('cfg[key]: ' + cfg[key]);
      this[key] = cfg[key];
    }
    console.log(this);
    console.log('this.foo: ' + this.foo);
    /* // if you comment this in, comment out the above for loop
    let objProperties = {}
    for (let key in cfg) {
        objProperties[key] = {
          configurable: true,
          enumerable: true,
          set: (function(val) {
              console.log('this[' + key + ']: ' + this[key]);
          }).bind(this)
        }
    }
    for (let key in cfg) {
      console.log('cfg[key]: ' + cfg[key]);
      this[key] = cfg[key];
    }
    Object.defineProperties(this, objProperties);
    for (let key in cfg) {
      console.log('cfg[key]: ' + cfg[key]);
      this[key] = cfg[key];
    }
    */
}
```

Comment: The properties set with setters need also getters.

Comment: @Teemu OK I will try that, for the time being I hadn't planned on doing anything with getters.  If you are indeed correct, you should probably add this as an answer so I can accept/upvote it.  I think this would certainly then be a worthy Q&A as it would seem to be a "gotcha".

Comment: I tried added a (empty) getter, and it didn't work: https://repl.it/@dexygen/GratefulSandyEidolonhelvum -- maybe I'll try adding functionality to the getter but I don't see why that would make a difference

Comment: But a getter is supposed to return a value ... See https://jsfiddle.net/fx6dcc48/ .

Comment: @Teemu Perfect!  Though I might need to tweak the implementation in the long run as I'd planned on clobbering `cfg` after everything was first set -- there is some functionality I do *not* want to execute on the first pass, and I figured testing for the existence of `cfg` might be the way to do that.  Anyway I still have a lot of playing around to do, but again I encourage you to write this up as an answer, of course though maybe with your level of rep you don't care if you get a little more?

Comment: @Teemu Sorry, deleted my comment because I see that the `new` _is_ doing something. Why would they be read-only? `this[key]` is _using_ the setters. Maybe I'm confused about what you mean.

Comment: @JLRishe Umh ... Yep, only that the setter in this particular case throws the value away.

Comment: @Teemu Ok, I missed that. But I still don't see why you would expect `this[key] = cfg[key];` to throw an error in strict mode.

Comment: @JLRishe No, you're right with this, it shouldn't, I've removed the comment.

Comment: You should rather use the arguments passed to the setter rather than fiddling around with context

Comment: do you really need setter here? why don't you use just the value descriptor rather than setter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I want to thank the first person to comment but he's declined to answer so I am posting my own based not only on his comment (the fact that I had not providde a `getter` more or less being the reason I was getting back `undefined` from my `setter`), but also addressing issues brought up by some of the other answers, one being the questioning of my use case, which I address with a comment in the `setter`.

Working code here: https://repl.it/@dexygen/javascript-defineProperty-working

```
let myObj = new ObjInstance({
    foo: 'foo',
    bar: 'bar',
    baz: 'baz'
});

function ObjInstance(cfg) {
    for (let key in cfg) {
      this[key] = cfg[key];

      Object.defineProperty(this, key, {
          configurable: true,
          enumerable: true,
          set: function(val) {
              cfg[key] = val;
              // additionally plan to emit an event
          },
          get: function() {
              return cfg[key];
          }
      });
    }

    console.log('this.foo: ' + this.foo);
    this.foo = 'foobarbaz';
    console.log('this.foo: ' + this.foo);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you use setter or getter, then it cannot have the same property name as the returned property. It seems that you try to do something like this:

```
var obj = {
  set a(param){
    console.log(this.a); //setter try to set a setter
  },
  get a(){
    return this.a;  //RangeError: Maximum call stack
  }
};
```

The property that is set or got by `setter` or `getter` must have different property name, eg `_foo`:

```
let myObj = new ObjInstance({
    foo: 'foo',
    bar: 'bar',
    baz: 'baz'
});

console.log(myObj);

function ObjInstance(cfg) {
    for (let key in cfg) {
      Object.defineProperty(this,key, {
          configurable: true,
          enumerable: true,
          set:(val)=>{
            this[`_${key}`] = key;
          },
          get:()=>{
            return this[`_${key}`];
          }
      });
      console.log('cfg[key]: ' + cfg[key]);
      this[key] = cfg[key];
    }
    console.log(this);
    console.log('this.foo: ' + this.foo);
}
```

or you can just store the values in the `getter`s like this:

```
let myObj = new ObjInstance({
    foo: 'foo',
    bar: 'bar',
    baz: 'baz'
});

console.log(myObj);

function ObjInstance(cfg) {
    for (let key in cfg) {
      Object.defineProperty(this,key, {
          configurable: true,
          enumerable: true,
          get:()=>{
            return key;
          }
      });
      console.log('cfg[key]: ' + cfg[key]);
      this[key] = cfg[key];
    }
    console.log(this);
    console.log('this.foo: ' + this.foo);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an alternative JavaScript backward compatible equivalent

```
function Handle( O ) {

var arr = [];

   for( var p in O ) {
    arr.push(
    ["get "+p+"(){ return O['"+p+"']; }, set "+p+"(x){ O['"+p+"'] = x; /*your emitter*/ }" ]
    );
   }
    return Function("O", "return {"+arr.join()+"}" )(O);
}
```

Comment: p.s.: in this variant the `new` operator is not required.

Answer (score -1):

Why is it that a nice and clean conventional JavaScript doesn't work for you?

```js
var myObj = new ObjInstance
(
  {
    foo: 'foo',
    bar: 'bar',
    baz: 'baz'
  }
);

function ObjInstance( cfg ) {
    for ( var key in cfg ) {
      this[ key ] = cfg[ key ];
    }
};

console.log( JSON.stringify( myObj ) );

myObj.bar = 'bar2';

console.log( JSON.stringify( myObj ) );
```

Comment: You are the second person to answer who questioned my use case, but at least the other stayed on topic and provided an answer that actually addresses the use of `defineProperty/set/get`.  In his case therefore I just edited out his questioning of my use case.  Your answer on the other hand does not address the issues brought up in my question whatsoever.

Comment: @GeorgeJempty - But of course it does - You want to be able to: 1. create new instances of objects using templates and 2. would also like to be able to assign new values to the keys of the new instance other than the default template values and 3. also be able to retrieve them with ease - THIS,  DOES ALL THAT YOU REQUIRE and it also does it in a nice, clean, easy to read & maintain ready to implement in a widely supported production code of JavaScript vanilla.

Comment: No it does *not* do "ALL THAT (I) REQUIRE", please see my own answer, with a comment within the `setter`: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47369376/34806  I don't believe one should have to explain their use case to begin with, but rather questions should stand on their own merits, and answers should directly address the *specific* issues brought up in those questions

Comment: You didn't answer my question - that was not the answer, nor final one - that was my question - you refused to answer. Instead you were being rude.

Comment: Your question "Why is it that a nice and clean conventional JavaScript doesn't work for you?" calls into question my use case, which, as I've explained, I don't believe should be called into question in *any* answer on SO, mine or anybody else's.  Plus your answer/responses make assumptions about my requirements.  I am not being rude whatsoever, trust me I know what is and is not rude, in fact I was just temporarily banned for *truly* being rude.  But I'm certainly not responding to you anymore since I do not seem to be getting though to you whatsoever