# How to permit object setter to write other properties of the object?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to define a setter as a kind of pass-through which allows me to detect changes on the underlying property:

```
var x={}
Object.defineProperty(x, "_a", { 
    value:-1, writeable:true, 
    enumerable:true, configurable:true 
})
Object.defineProperty(x, "a", {
  enumerable: true, configurable: true,
  get: function() { return this._a },
  set: function(val) { 
      this._a=val; 
      console.log(this,"note:x.a=",val,"=",this._a) 
  }
})
```

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47368150/543873) seems to suggest that this method should work.

However, when I try to assign to the "a" property, I am unable to set "_a", rendering my setter useless:

```
> {_a: -1} "note:x.a=" 1 "=" -1
< 1
```

If I substitute any other variable outside the object it works, but this is undesirable as I would have to have two separate objects, one for properties being watched and one for properties not being watched.  I would have to copy values from one to the other when a watch is added or removed, and I would have to add a conditional to every object access to allow for a second object lookup if the first one fails.

I'm making sure that "_a" is writeable, which I *think* from reading the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty) should be all I need to do.  What am I missing?

Comment: You spelt 'writable' wrong in your _a property. With your mistake, _a became immutable and never could change from -1. Corrected, it all works as you'd expect.

Comment: @Adam Oh wow, I just can't spell! :-D